# conectar em multiplos bancos de dados sqlserver

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Boa Noite, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em MVC 5 e c#,  tenho dois banco de dados SQLSERVER, sendo um para Desenvolvimento e outro para Produção.

Peço me informar como configurar WebConfig para aceitar essas duas conexões e se e preciso construir alguma classe que faça isso.

Melhor esclarecendo:

Quando desenvolvemos a aplicacao temos um servidor web de desenvolvimento que comunica com um servidor de banco de dados sqlserver de desenvolvimento, 
uma vez essa aplicacao estando pronta, ela sobe para o servidor web de producao o qual devera se comunicar com o servidor SQLSERVER de Producao.

O que preciso faze e configurar o webconfig par ele reconhecer em qual banco ele deve se comunicar sem ter que alterar isso manualmente como venho fazendo.

Comment: Você quer acessar as 2 conexões ao mesmo tempo?
Caso não precise você pode colocar a opção de escolher na tela de login por exemplo

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com detalhes do que está tentando fazer, deixando-a menos ampla e traga o código-fonte mostrando o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: se um é desenvolvimento e outro é produção, você não deve acessá-los ao mesmo tempo. Basta alterar no web.config quando for necessário alternar entre eles.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão no projeto MVC seu web.config já vai possuir dois arquivos de transformação base: Web.Debug.config e Web.Release.Config. Ambos já estão configurados para, quando compilado seu código, sobrescrever o web.config principal com as informações desejadas. Logo, se você publicar sua aplicação em Release Mode o seu web.config estará com a string de conexão do Web.Release.config, e caso publique em debug, o seu web.config estará com a string de conexão com Web.Debug.config.

Vale citar ainda que você não é limitado a apenas dois arquivos de transformação, você pode criar ainda outros de acordo com sua necessidade.